# Python enum.Enum: Create variables which i can assign enum.Enum members

Tags: python-3.x, enums, type-safety

Creating enumerations in Python 3.4+ is pretty easy:

```
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 10
    B = 20
```

This gets me a typedef MyEnum.
With this i can assign a variable:

```
x = MyEnum.A
```

So far so good.
However things start to get complicate if i like to use enum.Enum's as arguments to functions or class methods and want to assure that class attributes only hold enum.Enum members but not other values.

How can i do this? My idea is sth like this, which i consider more as a workaround than a solution:

```
class EnContainer:
    def __init__(self, val: type(MyEnum.A) = MyEnum.A):
        assert isinstance(val, type(MyEnum.A))
        self._value = val
```

Do you have any suggestions or do you see any problems with my approach? I have to consider about 10 different enumerations and would like to come to a consistent approach for initialization, setters and getters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `type(MyEnum.A)`, just use `MyEnum`:

```
def __init__(self, val: MyEnum = MyEnum.A):
    assert isinstance(val, MyEnum)
```

Never use `assert` for error checking, they are for program validation -- in other words, who is calling `EnContainer`?  If only your own code is calling it with already validated data, then `assert` is fine; but if code outside your control is calling it, then you should be using proper error checking:

```
def __init__(self, val: MyEnum = MyEnum.A):
    if not isinstance(val, MyEnum):
        raise ValueError(
                "EnContainer called with %s.%r (should be a 'MyEnum')"
                % (type(val), val)
                )
```

Comment: I see that it was not very clever to use assert in this case. Thank you for the hint. Is it right that `type(MyEnum.A) == type(MyEnum)` ? See: `type(MyEnum)` -> `enum.EnumMeta` but `type(MyEnum.A)` -> `<enum 'MyEnum'>`